# Kindle paperwhite

Tags: soft-question, math-software

Any thoughts on reading maths in papers using the Kindle Paperwhite?

I have been trying to find an answer elsewhere but it is difficult to to get an answer to this specific question.

Comment: You might want to read this [**Kindle Paperwhite Review**](http://us.gizmodo.com/5947435/kindle-paperwhite-review-forget-everything-else-this-is-the-e+reader-you-want). However, I couldn't recommend taking some math PDFs (lots of symbols, large sizes, lots of graphics, color pictures) off the web that you like, going to a tech store and playing with the things to see how it performs for you. I would compare and contrast to color variants, quick processors, lots of memory, page refresh rates, battery life, warranty ... Regards

Answer (score 5):

I would recommend getting something with a color screen and quick rendering capabilities. I personally find that I need to zoom in a lot while reading math pdf's and (especially) books, as well as swipe through pages quickly to find something. This becomes *extremely* annoying if your device lags as you'll be waiting upwards of a few seconds per page which adds up if you're trying to skim thirty pages. As well, switching between pdf's with ease is very useful. Don't take my word for it though, go to any electronics store and try one for yourself, download something off arxiv and play with it.